# Flux Decoding Exception : Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

Tags: json, spring, spring-webflux

While decoding *Flux* JSON to *Java* object, I am getting below exception:

```console
2019-02-25 13:44:39.136 TRACE [{}] 25292 --- [reactor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.r.f.c.ExchangeFunctions            : [762021a9] Response 200 OK, headers={masked}
2019-02-25 13:44:39.195 ERROR [{}] 25292 --- [reactor-http-nio-4] r.M.C.2                                  : | onError(org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 2, column: 3])
2019-02-25 13:44:39.196 ERROR [{}] 25292 --- [reactor-http-nio-4] r.M.C.2                                  : 
org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('[' (code 91)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 2, column: 3]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.Jackson2Tokenizer.tokenize(Jackson2Tokenizer.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Setting the mapper codec property as follows does not resolve the issue:

```java
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

Here dow the *JSON* response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "111",
    "description": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "description": "pqr"
  }
]
```

Here down the `WebClient` implementation:

```java
public Mono<List<ItemServiceResponse>> getItems(ItemServiceRequest itemServiceRequest) {
return webClient
        .post()
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON.toString())
        .body(Mono.just(itemServiceRequest), ItemServiceRequest.class)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(ItemServiceResponse.class)
        .collectList()
        .log();
}
```

Here is the Java Object:

```
@Builder 
@Data 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class ItemServiceResponse { 
  private String id; 
  private String description; 
}
```

Comment: What happens if you write the `ItemServiceResponse` in plain Java (instead of using Lombok) here?

Comment: Hi Brian, removed all Lombok annotations, but still the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A terrible problem!!! I wasted my 4-5 days figuring out what is wrong in my code and tried all permutation combination but nothing worked.

But guys, Postman was the culprit, yeah that's right.

The actual response structure of the JSON I was getting:

```
{
  [
    {
      "id": "111",
      "description": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "id": "222",
      "description": "pqr"
    }
  ]
}
```

And that is malformed JSON. But Postman was autocorrecting somehow and was giving a correct response as JSON mentioned in the question and I was not looking more on the response because the status code was coming as 200 success.

Fortunately, I triggered Curl command and got the root cause. Please don't believe postman... it is damn smart to correct things which are not required.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectMapper` is expecting a single object to be mapped from your *Json* repsonse as a `ItemServiceResponse` hence the exception (the mapper is expecting a *quote*).

You should update your `WebClient` invocation to map an `array` of `ItemServiceResponse`:

```java
public Mono<List<ItemServiceResponse>> getItems(ItemServiceRequest itemServiceRequest) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON.toString())
            .body(Mono.just(itemServiceRequest), ItemServiceRequest.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ItemServiceResponse[].class) // <-- array of ItemServiceResponse
            .collectList()
            .log();
}
```

Comment: I tried this way also, but not working. same exception

Comment: Could you try changing the response type to raw *application/json*: `.header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`